# PHP json_decode on a 32bit server

Tags: php, 32-bit, json

im writting a twitter mashup service. When i receive the json data, some of the twit ids are greater than **2147483647** (which is the maximum allowed integer on 32bit servers).

I came up with a solution that works, which is converting the integers to strings; that way the json_decode() function won't have any problems when trying to generate the array.

This is what i need to achieve:

**Before (original JSON data)**

```
[{"name":"john","id":5932725006},{"name":"max","id":4953467146}]
```

**After (solution applied)**

```
[{"name":"john","id":"5932725006"},{"name":"max","id":"4953467146"}]
```

I'm thinking of a preg_match implementation, but i have no idea on how to do it bullet-proof. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to capture the numbers and add the quotes, something like this:

```
$jsonString = '[{"name":"john","id":5932725006},{"name":"max","id":4953467146}]';

echo preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $jsonString);
//prints [{"name":"john","id":"5932725006"},{"name":"max","id":"4953467146"}]
```

Try the above example [here](http://codepad.org/hc0R9clY).

Comment: You'll want `"id":` in that expression, surely? Otherwise it will match any sequence of numbers, badly breaking any string that contains a digit.

Comment: exactly. it works fine... but it would be better if it would only match the digits near "id":

Comment: in fact... if there is "name":"junior2" it will become "junior"2"" with your code :s

Comment: Yeah, bobince is right. Try `preg_replace('/"id":(\d+)/', '"id":"$1"', $jsonString)`

Comment: Thx. i think some older PHP version may have this issue, while new do not. becoz i got a working json_decode in one machine, but not the one with php 5.2.3, at least. but the above solution works!

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP 5.2 those long ids will be parsed into a float, which though not ideal at least gives you another 21 bits of integer precision, which should easily be enough to store those ids. (A 64-bit server would be ideal of course.)

Comment: the server where this is running has both php4 and php5 environments. in order to activate php5 i have to set this flag in the .htaccess file:

AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php

Maybe this weird setting won't let me get the int2float feature. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: That should work, but you may, alas, still be running an older version of PHP5 too.

Answer (score 0):

If it comes down to it, you can attempt to use the `big_int` PECL extension. This lets PHP use numbers that are extraordinarily large, should you need to. It's a big leap, but if you're routinely dealing with numbers that border on the edge of mindnumbingness, you'll likely find it helpful.