# PHP json_decode integers and floats to string

Tags: php, json, numbers

I want to pre-parse a json an convert all numbers in the json (integers or float) to strings.

For example:

```
{
 "integer": 10000,
 "big_integer": 100000999499498485845848584584584,
 "float1" : 1.121212,
 "float2" : 8.226347662837406e+09
}
```

to this:

```
{
 "integer": "10000",
 "big_integer": "100000999499498485845848584584584",
 "float1" : "1.121212",
 "float2" : "8226347662.837406"
}
```

***Update***
I have found the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777382/php-json-decode-on-a-32bit-server?answertab=active#tab-top) but it does not work for floats:

```
$jsonString = '[{"name":"john","id":5932725006},{"name":"max","id":4953467146}]';

echo preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $jsonString);
//prints [{"name":"john","id":"5932725006"},{"name":"max","id":"4953467146"}]
```

***Update 2*** Fixed second float value. It had two points.

Comment: I have found this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777382/php-json-decode-on-a-32bit-server?answertab=active#tab-top but it does not work for floats.

Comment: You can set that comment as a update in your question

Comment: Does it *need* to be in PHP, or is another language solution acceptable?

Comment: Yes, It need to be in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: It should work

```
echo preg_replace('/\: *([0-9]+\.?[0-9e+\-]*)/', ':"\\1"', $jsonString);
```

Comment: It does not work. It returns: `{"integer""10000","big_integer""100000999499498485845848584584584","float1""1.121212","float2""8.226347662".837406e+09}`

Comment: Sorry, it does not work but really returns this: `{"integer""10000","big_integer""100000999499498485845848584584584","float1""1.121212","float2""8.226347662837406e+09"}` with new new update2 in the question

Comment: Thank you @jibran-bhat. It works. Although now I have another problem related to this. I want to convert hte json to an object and then get the original json but the object has to use string for json numbers. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123862/encoding-and-decoding-floats-in-json-with-php-without-losing-precision

Comment: Never ever use regex for jsons. For example this could corrupt json containing strings with colons and numbers. And many other potential issues.

Comment: Why is this accepted?  It fails on the scientific float: "float2" : 8.226347662837406e+09     and be aware it will also fail on lists "[1.2, 3.0]"

Answer (score 10):

Use `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` option:

`json_decode($jsonString, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)`

Answer (score 1):

I like this is solution for big float:

```
$json = '{"data":[[0.00004639,683724.2687321],[0.00004658,190091.61007863]]}';

$json = preg_replace('/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/', '"$1.$2"', $json);

print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```

This is code replace only float to string and you should use it before call json_decode()

JSON:

```
{"data":[[0.00004639,683724.2687321],[0.00004658,190091.61007863]]}
```

After decode:

```
 array (
      'data' => array (
          0 => array (
            0 => '0.00004639',
            1 => '683724.2687321',
          ),
          1 => array (
            0 => '0.00004658',
            1 => '190091.61007863',
          ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex which works on float numbers, and it works for **attributes**, but also **arrays**. It also works for **negative** floats.

```
preg_replace('/((?<=":)|(?<=\[)|(?<=,))(?<!")(-?\d+\.\d+)(?!")/', '"$2"', $json)
```

If you also want to cover for scientific notations, this will work but this will also convert integers to strings

```
preg_replace('/((?<=":)|(?<=\[)|(?<=,))(?<!")(-?[\d\.]+((e|E)(\+|-)\d+)?)(?!")/', '"$2"', $json)
```

The inspiration was taken from this answer, i've adjusted the regex to be even able to use replace, and expanded it to work with arrays and negatives https://stackoverflow.com/a/35008486

Tested with string
`{"array":[[0.00004639,683724.2687321],[0.00004658,190091.61007863,190091.61007863]],"and_finally":{"negative_float":-1.123,"negative_int":-1,"first_name":"sa123mp5e-19le","last_name":"la5.1e+5stn543.123,ame","integer":"100","another_float":"1555.20","int":100,"float":1555.20,"floatAsString":"1555.20","date":"2015-01-01 15:23:51","somefloat":[14,23],"somefloat2":[5e-7,23.33],"scientific_negative_float":5.2e-7,"scientific_positive_float":5E+19}}`

**Issues**

This will fail if there is whitespace in the json (which in production environment is never the case). If you have whitespace then you could just remove all whitespace with this (but if you have sentences anywhere in the json, this will merge it into a single long word)

```
preg_replace('/\s/', '', $json)
```

Another issue with this approach is that the array matches are not safe if they are found within a string. These will be rare, but they still might happen.

This will fail `{"last_name":"lastn,543.123ame"}`

This will also fail
`{"last_name":"lastn[543.123ame"}`

Unfortunately there is no straightforward way of getting around these limitations using only one regex pass. However, if you have a response that contains purely numbers, then this works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was looking for regex to match also negative numbers, here it is:

```
echo preg_replace('/\: *([0-9]+\.?[0-9e+\-]*|-[0-9]+\.?[0-9e+\-]*)/', ':"\\1"', $jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most correct way to wrap such numbers in quotation marks, making them strings. This does not distort the original appearance of the json string and takes into account the scientific format. [Github](https://github.com/alglyzin/json) ([composer](https://packagist.org/packages/alglyzin/json))

```
$regexp = '/"(\s*)\:(\s*)(\-?\d+([eE][\+|\-]?\d+|\.\d+)+)(\s*[,(\s*)|\}])/';
$json_string = preg_replace($regexp, "$1:$2\"$3\"$5", $json);
```