# Convert JSON integers and floats to strings

Tags: php, json, regex, pcre

I want to pre-parse a JSON and convert integer and float value to string in the JSON. Also there are some string values in JSON.

For example:

```
{
    "first_name": "sample",
    "last_name": "lastname",
    "integer" : 100,
    "float" : 1555.20
}
```

I just use `preg_replace()` like this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108803/php-json-decode-integers-and-floats-to-string/30109477#30109477/):

```
echo preg_replace('/\: *([0-9]+\.?[0-9e+\-]*)/', '"\\1"', $jsonString);
```

But its not working if I have a string value in my array, it only works if there are only integer and float values in array.

Can anyone help explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
$str = '{"first_name":"sample",
          "last_name": "lastname",
          "integer" : 100,
          "float" : 1555.20,
          "createddate":"2015-06-25 09:57:28"}';

$result = preg_replace("/(\"\w+\":\s*?)(\d+\.?[^,\}]*\b)/imu",'$1"$2"',$str);

var_dump($result);
```

---

```
// output:
string(121) "{"first_name":"sample",
"last_name": "lastname",
"integer" : 100,
"float" : 1555.20,
"createddate":"2015-06-25 09:57:28"}"
```

Comment: this code works fine but when i add a new field datetime then this code gives output like this :   "2015-06-25 08:"15":"14"" .

Comment: it gives the same output.

Comment: @NiraliKavar, strange ... I suppose that we have worked with different initial strings. What is your initial string?

Comment: my initial string is like that : {"first_name":"sample","last_name": "lastname","integer" : 100, "float" : 1555.20, "createddate":"2015-06-25 09:57:28"}.

Comment: now json is generate as i want but it gives one more javascript error like that :  TypeError: float.toFixed is not a function..

Comment: Your initial task was "convert integer and float value to string" and `toFixed` isn't a property of non-numeric variable types. Use this approach: `parseFloat(float).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [*lookaheads and lookbehinds*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)!

```
$newJson = preg_replace('/("\s*:\s*)(?<!")[\d\.]+(?!")/', '\1"\2"', $json);
```

You can visualize this [here](https://regex101.com/r/aO7pA3/2).

`(?<!")` is a negative lookbehind. It is a "zero length expression" meaning that it doesn't actually match a character; it just prevents a match from occurring if a `"` was there. `(?!")` is a negative lookahead, and works the same way, but matches forward instead of backward.

Comment: I have one more field for date and its showing me like this, entry_date":"2"015"-"06"-"25" "10": how can i resolve this ?

Comment: i used that new string from your edit but it makes all integer value blank,, Like this [ "integer"":" ] thanks Will :)